# Force download without losing the format?

Tags: php, http-headers, download, force-download

I want to download text file from server to client, the code is working but after I download the text file it shows an extra blank line at top.

How do I remove that line or how do I get the original format of the text file into the client machine?

Here is my code:

```
$code = $_POST["Code"];
$File = "my$code.txt"; 
if (file_exists($File))
{
    header("Content-Type:text/plain");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$File");
    header("Content-Length:" . filesize("$File"));
    $fp = fopen("$File", "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
}
```

Comment: Looks like file encoding miss-match it troubling you.

Comment: It could be a number of things, or a mix of things. An answer has been posted which is one possible reason, another is to make sure there isn't already a space in the input; I've seen that happen before. Also, not using a closing `?>` tag could help. Again, too many possible reasons. Sidenote: Why the `$` in `my$code.txt` or is that a typo?

Comment: because user type code in textbox and hit download button. and all text file starts with " 'my'+$code.txt "as same for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the all tags are closed ( opening and closing).
Remove all blank lines from php page.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is **nothing** in front of the opening **<?php** tag.